# Create an image of text, for compositing with other images, for use in a SpriteKit app

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to create simple icons which feature a background image, and a small integer (<100).

I have this code from a SwiftUI app I wrote, which could almost do this:

```
struct InitialIcon: View {
    var str: String
    var bgImage: Image
    var size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 64.0, height: 64.0)
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
                .size(size)
                .background(content: { bgImage } )
            Text(str).font(.system(size: size.width*0.6, weight: .bold, design: .rounded)).foregroundColor(.white)
        }.frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }
}
```

The problem is that the **ImageRenderer** class they offer to turn this View into an image requires the renderer to be run in a **@MainActor** function, and this makes me think I'm using a semi truck to get chips and a soda from the corner store.

At the end I need a rectangular image made from a background image, and a styled text string *centered* on top of that, resolved to a simple flat image which I can hand to **SpriteKit** as a game piece.

Comment: ImageRenderer is indeed the recommended way to draw stuff into an offscreen context and capture it into an image. I have very little experience with SwiftUI, but MainActor is just a way to tell the system that your code needs to be run on the main thread (as all UIKit code needs to be.)

Comment: fyi you can also do this inside SpriteKit using [render-to-texture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1520114-texture). build a node with image and label (similar to your swiftui code above), then render it to a texture. assign the texture to a spritenode.